# How to add a second UILabel to a UIButton, configurable per UIControlState

Tags: cocoa-touch, uibutton, uilabel, calayer, drawrect

I want to display 2 strings (at different positions in the button) with different fonts and colors (I'm using the button's `setTitle` for one, and I need another one), and some attributes must be changed based on the current `UIControlState` (like the color).

So, I'm searching the best way to add a second label to a `UIButton`.
I need the label to be configurable per `UIControlState` (I want a different color for `UIControlStateNormal` and `UIControleStateHighlighted` for example).

I've tried the following approches:

- Subclass a `UIButton` and use `drawRect`: while not recommended (and I now understand why), I don't think it's even possible, it looks like the button's `drawRect` method is called (and after the one of my subclass) even if I don't call super.
- Create a new `UILabel` and add it as a `subview` to my button: this is working quite well, except I don't know how to change the color when the `UIControlState` of the button is changing
- Create a new layer and use `drawLayer`: I don't know how to get the `drawLayer` method to be called every time the button state is changing (my `drawLayer` only gets called once, when I use `setNeedsDisplay` just after adding my layer to the button)

Is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to do, or maybe one of those solutions might work (with a few tweaks)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I found a working solution (for my problem at least).

I'm subclassing the `UIButton` class (it works for me, since I'm using a custom drawn button anyway), and I override the `titleRectForContentRect` method that gets called everytime the title has to be displayed (including after a state change, just before display).

I added an `UILabel` to the button's view to display the second string I want, and during the `titleRectForContentRect`, I compute the correct `frame` location for my label, I update my label's text  font and color based on the button's state (`self.state`), and that's all I need.

Answer (score 2):

The second of your approach works fine. Just add 2 targets: First update to "normal state" target using "all touch events". Second update to "highlighted" using "touch down" event.

If the states are not only changed by touches and want to handle this more generally, Id suggest multithreading. All you really need is calling performSelectorInBackground when initializing all this elements (the selector updates label according to button state) and then again call same performSelectorInBackground on the end of "update label" method, creating an infinite loop.

Comment: Seems a little complicated for the simple thing I'm trying to do, but I suppose it's because UIButton is a class that cannot be easily subclassed.
I'll take a look at that solution if nothing else comes out.